# AWS Elasticsearch endpoint unauthorized

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-elasticsearch

When I click on elasticsearch domain endpoint it tells me unauthorized. Moreover, I tried using curl and the same issue. I've written a lambda function that takes data from dynamodb and tries to put into es and I'm getting 403 status.

Configuration for es domain:

- Allow open access
- Created a master user (not sure the exact function of this. probably used for accessing kibana?)
- Following is the permission:

```
{   "Version": "2012-10-17",   "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-west-2:[ACCOUNT_ID]:domain/[ES_DOMAIN]/*"
    }   ] }
```

Lambda has the following role:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "es:ESHttpPost",
        "es:ESHttpPut",
        "dynamodb:DescribeStream",
        "dynamodb:GetRecords",
        "dynamodb:GetShardIterator",
        "dynamodb:ListStreams",
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Does anyone know what is wrong or what am I missing here?

Comment: Does the security group attached to your Elasticsearch cluster has port open for your machine?